# Camera component returns null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to disable a Camera component to change between my cameras.
But when I try to get my GameObject's Camera component, it returns null.

Here is my GameObject:

[image]

And here is where my code crashes:

```
void respawn(){
    cameraDead.transform.position = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x, cameraDead.transform.position.y, player.transform.position.z);

    cameraDead.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = true;//It crashes right here
    camera.GetComponent<Camera>().enabled = false;
    player.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(new Vector3(-27f, 0f, -8.35f), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,90,0)));
    isDead = true;
}
```

The error message says the pointer is returning null. So it couldn't find the Component.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your cameraDead field initialized by unity?

Comment: What exactly is the error message you get?

Comment: Your GameObject is named `CameraDead` in the screenshot but in code you are using `cameraDead`. Do you have `cameraDead` defined elsewhere? Also, you could try following [Unity's example](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultipleCameras.html) with multiple cameras and get a reference to the Camera component by assigning it in the Inspector.

Comment: How do you define `cameraDead`? Are you dragging that gameobject into a field in the component that has `respawn()` ?  It doesn't seem to be null because `cameraDead.transform.yadda yadda` line doesn't fail, but it seems to be declared to a completely different gameobject than the one in the image.

Comment: @jeuxjeux20 yes it is

Comment: @derHugo, here is my error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Zombie.respawn () (at Assets/Scripts/Zombie.cs:138)
Zombie.howNear () (at Assets/Scripts/Zombie.cs:115)
Zombie.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Zombie.cs:47)

Comment: @LewsTherin, "cameraDead" is just the variable name, it is, actually, the "CameraDead" GameObject. And referencing the component in the inspector works, but for what I want It can't be done... and even if I try to do this, I would want to solve this problem. I saw some people with the same problem but no solution.

Comment: @Ruzihm, I've already tested that, translating the gameObject at the same time that I try to get the Camera component. The Camera moves, but I still can't get that specific component.

Comment: You tried to click on cameraDead field in the inspector to see if it points to the correct game object? Alternatively you can create a field of type Camera and assign the component directly through Unity inspector, then use aCameraComponent.enable. Anyway, you are just forgetting something simple/obvious, look your inspector closely.

Comment: Can you just to be sure add a screenshot of your references in the inspector the moment the error is thrown? Since you method is called `respawn` ... Amy chance the object you try to access is destroyed?

Comment: null reference exceptions sometimes occur on the next line after the real error. IS player defined too?

Comment: @Float Can you show the code where the `cameraDead` variable is defined? If you don't have something like `var cameraDead = GameObject.Find("CameraDead");` then just using `cameraDead` won't work (and would throw a NullReferenceException when you try to access a property) because there is no automatic mapping of GameObjects to variables in Unity scripts. You could also attach the Visual Studio debugger and set the debugger to break when NullReferenceExceptions are thrown to see what object is null and throwing that exception.

Comment: Have you created any classes that are also called `Camera` ? Unity may be looking for a `Camera` component that isn't the same as the `UnityEngine.Camera` you have attached to `cameraDead`

Answer (score 0):

When a component is disabled or a game object is inactive, you can't fetch it using GetComponent. By your code it seems that the Camera component of CameraDead is disabled at first, and then you're trying to fetch it at enable it.

You can easily solve this by caching components. Something like this:

- Firstly keep both Camera components enabled in the scene.

  ```
  public GameObject cameraDead;
  public GameObject camera;
  private Camera dead_cam;
  private Camera cam;

  void Start()
  {
      dead_cam = cameraDead.GetComponent<Camera>();
      cam = camera.GetComponent<Camera>();
      dead_cam.enabled = false;
  }

  //....

  void respawn(){
      cameraDead.transform.position = new Vector3(player.transform.position.x, cameraDead.transform.position.y, player.transform.position.z);

      dead_cam.enabled = true;
      cam.enabled = false;
      player.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(new Vector3(-27f, 0f, -8.35f), Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,90,0)));
      isDead = true;
  }
  ```